# Getting Abstract method error even after providing valid absolute chrome path

Tags: java, bdd

Error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void loadSystemProperties()' of abstract class org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder
```

Actual result:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0

Scenario: Successful login with valid credentials                        # Features/login1.feature:4
  Given User launch chrome browser                                       # stepDefinitions.steps.user_launch_chrome_browser()
    ** ** java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void loadSystemProperties()' of abstract class org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.****
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:495)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createServiceWithConfig(ChromeDriverService.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:71)
    at stepDefinitions.steps.user_launch_chrome_browser(steps.java:35)
    at ✽.User launch chrome browser(file:///C:/Users/User/eclipse-workspace/BDD/./Features/login1.feature:5)

  When user open URL "http://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/login"           # stepDefinitions.steps.user_open_url(java.lang.String)
  And user enters email as "admin@yourstore.com" and password as "admin" # stepDefinitions.steps.user_enters_email_as_and_password_as(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  And Click on login                                                     # stepDefinitions.steps.click_on_login()
  Then Page title should be "Dashboard / nopCommerce administration"     # stepDefinitions.steps.page_title_should_be(java.lang.String)
  When user click on logout link                                         # stepDefinitions.steps.user_click_on_logout_link()
  Then page title should be "Your store. Login"
  And Close browser                                                      # stepDefinitions.steps.close_browser()
FAILED: runScenario("Successful login with valid credentials", "Login")
        Runs Cucumber Scenarios
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void loadSystemProperties()' of abstract class org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:495)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createServiceWithConfig(ChromeDriverService.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:71)
    at stepDefinitions.steps.user_launch_chrome_browser(steps.java:35)
    at ✽.User launch chrome browser(file:///C:/Users/User/eclipse-workspace/BDD/./Features/login1.feature:5)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

testrun class:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUzuv.png)

steps class:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iQNo.png)
Expected result:

Web browser should load and open the provided url......

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)